# Wordpress Stylesheet isn't updating on front end

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, stylesheet

I'm working on a site for a client that was built by someone else, and I'm having issues with a stylesheet not updating on the front end

The site is http://www.hamiltonkarate.co.nz/, and I've tried to update the stylesheet and footer files. Now the footer file updates, but the stylesheet doesn't. I've tried deleting the stylesheet from the server but it's still there somehow, even though I can't find any cached files on the server.

The other weird part is that if I go into the theme editor in the dashboard, it shows up my updated stylesheet there. I've checked the relative paths etc, I've debugged, but I can't find out why the sheet isn't updated. I've tried hard refresh, other browsers/computers, and even incongnito mode with no luck.

I've uploaded the updated css to http://www.hamiltonkarate.co.nz/wp-content/themes/hamiltonkarate/css/screen.css, and if I update the CSS link in developer tools it works fine.

Can anyone see what may be going wrong here?

Comment: Ok it randomly decided to suddenly work, but would still be curious to find out what may have gone wrong?

Comment: I seem to be getting the updated CSS http://www.hamiltonkarate.co.nz/wp-content/themes/hamiltonkarate/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Please check file permission for your css file. It should be writeable

Comment: thanks it's not that. Somehow it's referencing old versions via version numbers which aren't even set. :(